# How to run several tasks as a group?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I created two tasks to assist me in the development of a web site:

```json
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build site",
            "command": "jekyll b --watch --incremental",
            "type": "shell",
            "group": "build"
        },
        {
            "taskName": "serve site",
            "command": "./_devd -ol _site",
            "type": "shell",
            "group": "build"
        }
    ]
}
```

I can start them one by one with <kbd>F1</kbd> → Run Task (so I need to issue the sequence twice, once for each task) and I end up with two tasks running at the same time.

**Is it possible to automate this and run a group of tasks at the same time?** [I thought](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks) that the `group` entry would, well, group them together but it is not the case (they are just recognized as belonging to the `build` or `test` group - and I did not find a way to start the whole group at once).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the `"dependsOn"` attribute. If you want to run the `"build site"` task first, add it as the `"dependsOn"` of the `"serve site"` task. If you want both to run together, make another task that depends on both the `"build site"` and `"serve site"` tasks.

Here is an example of building the site before serving it:

```js
{
  "taskName": "build site",
  "command": "jekyll b --watch --incremental",
  "type": "shell",
  "group": "build"
},
{
  "taskName": "serve site",
  "command": "./_devd -ol _site",
  "type": "shell",
  "group": "build",
  "dependsOn": "build site" // <--- Added this
},
```

Not aware of a cleaner way to do this with long running tasks but...

Here is an example of running both tasks at the same time:

```js
{
  "taskName": "Run Everything", // <-- Bind this task to a key
  "dependsOn": [ "build site", "serve site" ]
},
{
  "taskName": "build site",
  "command": "jekyll b --watch --incremental",
  "type": "shell"
},
{
  "taskName": "serve site",
  "command": "./_devd -ol _site",
  "type": "shell"
}
```

---

**Update**: Here's a [link to the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_compound-tasks) for the new `tasks.json` template (v2.0.0).  The portion relevant to this question is that `taskName` has been renamed to `label`, but `dependsOn`'s value remains the same.

Comment: Thanks, but this will not work because "build site" is a task which does not end. Both tasks do not end, actually, and must be ran in parallel.

Comment: May want to look into vscode's background option for tasks. I've not used it, so I do not know the limitations. https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_background-watching-tasks